# can I override the version block in a dll?

Tags: c++, version-control, resources, linker, revision

Suppose I have built a lot of dlls from a certain revision of the svn repository.  (It might by any revisioning system)

I am able to create a resource file containing an entry that denotes the revision number.

Can I link that resource file into the dll's I have already built?  Some sort of `editbin` or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a small program to do this, using the UpdateResource function in Windows NT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The resource compiler uses the C pre-processor.  You can simply use a #define in a header file you #include in your .rc file.  Or use the /D command line option for rc.exe.  You can use the macro symbol in your resource definition.